# Get correct configurable product image on my order page

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

i am want to show correct product image on my order details page:

I am using it as:

```
$_item = $block->getItem();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());

$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
```

but showing main product image its not showing child product image. here i am want to show correct configurable product image.

Please help.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below code to show the correct configurable's child product image.

```
<?php
    $_item = $block->getItem();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $_product = $productRepository->get($_item->getSku());
    $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
?>
```

Check the screenshot.

[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes getSku is correct way :)